# Zend Framework way of dealing with sessions and "remember me"

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-session

I read I should increase `gc_maxlifetime` in `php.ini` to the same large value (weeks) as the one I'm telling `Zend_Session::rememberMe()`. Is this good practice? Is there a reason not to increase `gc_maxlifetime` to more than half an hour or so?

Comment: As a side note: if you are trying to achieve a "remember me" function that keeps users logged in, you can't do it with sessions, because for the users that do not want that, each time the browser opens you will start a new session. If you increase this value to 'weeks' you will have dead session files kept for long time.

Comment: @venimus so what would be the good way of doing this?

Comment: just store a cookie and reinitialize automatically the login routine when the cookie is set but there is no session.

Comment: @SMka I want to see for a few more days if there are any new ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good practice. if you have many (thousands) site users - you can code custom session handler. for example, to support different directory structure.

like `/sessiondir/0/1/5/0152837462938587.sess` to minimize server load while reading dir with many files

Comment: gc_maxlifetime tells garbage collector how long to keep session files. If you set rememberMe() to 1 week it will simply set your cookie to that expiration time, but gc have no clue about that and removes sessions according to gc_maxlifetime. Basically you may end up with missing sessions after gc_maxlifetime passes

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know how to do custom session handling in Zend Framework?

Comment: @cambraca: it is not Zend action. http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php